# read variable value from property block using key value pair using shell script

Tags: shell, properties, scripting, key-value

I am trying to read a environment property in .ini format and get different value for different environment

here is the file look like

```
[key_value1 env_value1]
TOMCAT_SERVER=abc
APP_URL_LIST=%TOMCAT_URL%TOMCAT_PORT%/EnterpriseMessaging/
TOMCAT_INSTANCE=ENT-SMS-env_value1
TOMCAT_PORT=8169

[key_value2 env_value2]
TOMCAT_SERVER=xyz
APP_URL_LIST=%TOMCAT_URL2%TOMCAT_PORT%/EnterpriseMessaging/
TOMCAT_INSTANCE=ENT-SMS-env_value2
TOMCAT_PORT=8177
```

I want to read the underline dynamic variables that changed based on key pairs key_value and env_value pairs and read using a bash script

Can you please help??

Comment: Is it for `bash` or `batch`?

Comment: What are your inputs and desired output? You've got some close votes on your question, so you need to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
thekey="value2";sed '/\[key_'"$thekey"'/,/^$/!d;/\[key_'"$thekey"'\|^$/d' infile
```

You can subtitute value2 by valuen if you want to get environment property for valuen.